# yt:statistics / view count not returned with v2 api

Tags: youtube-api

I am not able to get yt:statistics and corresponding view count using youtube v2 api

Search URI:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/park/competition?orderby=viewCount&max-results=50&v=2&format=5&fields=entry(title,content,media:group,yt:statistics,yt:rating,gd:rating)

When I print the feed and look for statistics, I can not found it. I believe I was able to get it until last week.

I use PYTHON gdata lib to send/receive requests. It looks like for some feeds I am getting statistics. Does it not come for every feed??

Any pointers??

UPDATE: Similar observations for yt:rating.

Is there a minimum guarantee that yy api provides for statistics/rating?

Without a minimum guarantee, does it not become un-reliable?

Comment: Same issue here. All of a sudden yt:statistics disappeared from the feeds which is causing my application to show the wrong number of views. Hope that someone can point us towards the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [YouTube-Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/)?

Not sure what the equivalent call in the Python library would be - but for example, this url will get the top viewed videos:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports
  ?metrics=views
  &dimensions=video
  &max-results=10
  &sort=-views
  &start-index=1
  &start-date={first date of interest}
  &enddate={last date of interest}
  &ids={your channel id}
```

You should be able to use the same OAuth token that you're using for the YouTube Data API v2.